# pyspark how can I combine column values if columns have a same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an idea to combine dataframe values (a list) in different rows with the same key.
The combination must have a same value or more in different rows, so I can not just use `df.groupBy('id')` to get the result.

Following is the example:

```
+---------+--------------------+
|id       |num_list            |
+---------+--------------------+
|apple    |[11, 12]            |
|apple    |[11, 13 ,14]        |
|apple    |[10, 22, 25]        |
|banana   |[15, 26]            |
|banana   |[15, 29]            |
|banana   |[15, 27]            |
+---------+--------------------+
```

we can find `id=apple` have two record and two lists like: `[11, 12],[11, 13, 14]`, so they would be combined to a new record `id=apple,num_list=[11, 12, 13, 14]`

But `id=apple,num_list=[10, 22, 25]` will not be combined.

and this is the answer i want:

```
+---------+--------------------+
|id       |num_list            |
+---------+--------------------+
|apple    |[11, 12, 13, 14]    |
|apple    |[10, 22, 25]        |
|banana   |[15, 26, 27, 29]    |
+---------+--------------------+
```

**Edit:**

There are some rules that I have to explain.

Just as @Usernamenotfound commented,

Assuming apple have three values `[11, 12, 14]`, `[9, 13 ,14]`, and `[12,13,27]`, the answer will be `[9, 11, 12, 13 ,14, 27]` not `[9, 11, 12, 13 ,14]` and`[12,13,27]`.

There are some new example:

```
+--------------------+------------+
|                  id|num_list    |
+--------------------+------------+
|apple               |         [0]|
|apple               |         [0]|
|apple               |         [1]|
|apple               |         [1]|
|apple               |         [2]|
|apple               |         [3]|
|apple               |         [4]|
|apple               |         [5]|
|apple               |         [6]|
|apple               |         [6]|
|apple               |         [7]|
|apple               |      [7, 8]|
|apple               |         [9]|
|apple               |         [9]|
|apple               |         [9]|
|apple               |     [9, 10]|
|apple               | [9, 17, 18]|
|apple               |        [10]|
|apple               |        [10]|
|apple               |        [10]|
+--------------------+------------+
```

and if i tried the code from @mayank would get wrong answer.

```
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              id|num_list                                                                               |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|apple                           |[0]                                                                                    |
|apple                           |[0]                                                                                    |
|apple                           |[1]                                                                                    |
|apple                           |[2]                                                                                    |
|apple                           |[3]                                                                                    |
|apple                           |[4]                                                                                    |
|apple                           |[5]                                                                                    |
|apple                           |[6]                                                                                    |
|apple                           |[8, 7]                                                                                 |
|apple                           |[9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 36, 37, 38]|
|apple                           |[12]                                                                                   |
|apple                           |[14]                                                                                   |
|apple                           |[24]                                                                                   |
|apple                           |[31]                                                                                   |
|apple                           |[32]                                                                                   |
|apple                           |[33, 34]                                                                               |
|apple                           |[35]                                                                                   |
|apple                           |[39]                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can explode first and then do a groupBy and collect_set. Or write a UDF maybe.

Comment: @philantrovert  If I use `explode` and then `groupBy ` would combine `[10, 22, 25]` in the result which is not the answer i want.

Comment: Oh, got it. For rows that are next to each other.

Comment: Do you want to only combine items where the first list item in `num_list` is the same?

Comment: @philantrovert Do you have any idea to deal with this combination ?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Not the first item! If there are two `num_list` from differ row with same `id=apple` like as [11, 12, 14]  and [9, 13 ,14], answer will be` [9, 11, 12, 13 ,14]`.

Comment: @chilun what if there are more than one pair of items which match?

Comment: @chilun and what if at the end of one such combine operation, there are two more rows which meet the criteria?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound thanks for reply! Could you give me some example of question you ask? I do not really understand the problem!

Comment: assuming apple has three values `[11, 12, 14]`,  `[9, 13 ,14]`, and `[12,13,27]`. Do you want it to return `[9, 11, 12, 13 ,14]` and `[12,13,27]` or just `[9, 11, 12, 13 ,14, 27]`

Comment: @Usernamenotfound The answer will be `[9, 11, 12, 13 ,14, 27]` in your example.14 ,13,12 connect three list to be one.

Comment: @chilun please update your question with these cases. I can think of ways to do it in python on the top of my head and not PySpark. Maybe someone else can get to it before me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160685/discussion-between-chilun-and-usernamenotfound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient solution, but it solves your problem.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def get_combinations(lis):
   final = []

   for li in lis:
       if [y for y in final if [z for z in li if z in y]]:
           found = [y for y in final if [z for z in li if z in y]][0]
           to_add = list(set(found + li))
           final[final.index(found)] = to_add
       else:
           final.append(li)
   return final

apply_udf = F.udf(lambda x:get_combinations(x),ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))

df = df.groupby('id').agg(F.collect_list('num_list').alias('num_list'))\
        .select(['id', F.explode(apply_udf('num_list')).alias('num_list')])
```

Comment: I tried the code and I confused that if I changed the differ dataset, the code would get the wrong answer. I updated the example above. Thanks!

Comment: If i only test `get_combinations` function by num_list=[[0], [0], [1], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [6], [7], [7, 8], [9], [9], [9], [9, 10]], it will get wrong answer. I can not figure it out.

Comment: what you explained above in edit works for this code. If two or more lists will have atleast one common value, they will be combined into one with set(which leads to removal of repeated elements). If two lists do not have any value in common, they will become two separate records. The line if any(y for y in final if any(z for z in li if z in y)) ensures this.

Comment: For num_list which you said above, what result do you want exactly?

Comment: okay so i got the problem. any([0]) returns False. I have made the necessary changes. try it now.

Comment: Thanks for help! That is what I need.